# Avoid CakePHP's Auth component to display authentication error messages

Tags: cakephp, components, authentication

I would like to get rid of Auth component error messages, specially the **authError message** that comes whenever I try to access a non-allowed action.

Just to be sure, I double check that there is no `$this->Session->flash()` call anywhere in the layout. Besides, setting an empty value does not work, as the component has a default message value.

I am using the Auth component with the following configuration in AppController class:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'userModel' => 'WebUser',
            'loginAction' => '/login',
            'loginRedirect' => '/',
            'logoutRedirect' => '/login',
            'autoRedirect' => false,
        ),
        'Session',
        ...
     ...
}
```

For *login* and *logout* redirections I have setup two routes:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'web_users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

The *login* action within *WebUser* controller is almost empty; I only change the default layout:

```
function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Sign in');
}
```

Finally, I have a very simple *login.ctp* layout file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

When I access `http://example.com/login` there is no problem, no messages, just the login form. However I get the default *authError* message when requesting any other action, just after the Auth component redirects to the *login* action. Two questions arise:

1. <strike>Why is the Auth component displaying flash messages when there is no `$this->Session->flash()` call anywhere?</strike> (see update 2 below)
2. How can I setup an empty/null value in *authError* attribute?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I came up with a really ugly solution: I created an element login_error.ctp and assigned to the flashElement attribute in Auth component initialization:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'flashElement' => 'login_error',
        ...
     ...
}
```

In login_error.ctp I just compare with the *authError* default message:

```
<?php if ( $message !== 'You are not authorized to access that location.' ): ?>
<div id="flashMessage" class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It works, but I hate it!

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to dogmatic69 answer I forced myself to check everything again. I finally found where the call to `$this->Session->flash()` was being made. It was on a little view element that I had wrote before. It had nothing to do with login/logout stuff so I did not pay attention to that file.

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks to [SpawnCxy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950417/avoid-cakephps-auth-component-to-display-authentication-error-messages/4952907#4952907) as well. Copying the Auth component and making custom modifications is a better approach than string comparison.

Comment: What is the exact message being displayed?

Comment: The default set in Auth component: 'You are not authorized to access that location.'. Of course, I'm trying to avoid overwriting the component :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just remove `$this->Session->flash('auth')` from your view/layout.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1467/flash

Comment: Thanks! I checked everything again (even with a `grep -R auth`), and I finally found the call. It was on a little element that I had wrote before. It had nothing to do with login/logout stuff so I did not pay attention to that file.

Comment: Indeed! Is it possible to mark two answers? SpawnCxy answer helped me as well :)

Comment: only one correct answer per question, you can up vote a few though

Answer (score 8):

In CakePHP 2.1 in my AppController, I am using this to override my "auth" flash messages.
Here is my $components:

```
  public $components = array(
      'Acl',
      'Auth' => array(
          'flash' => array(
            'element' => 'info',
            'key' => 'auth',
            'params' => array()
          ),
          'authorize' => array(
              'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
          ),
      ),
      'Session',
  );
```

I am uncertain about if you can do this in previous versions of Cake.
Also, you can do:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  //Configure AuthComponent.
  $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
  $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
  $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => NULL);
  $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => NULL);
  $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => NULL);
  $this->Auth->authError = __('You must be logged in to view this page.');
  $this->Auth->loginError = __('Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.');
  $this->Auth->flash = array(
    'element' => 'info',
    'key' => 'auth',
    'params' => array()
  );
}
```

That works too! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to make the Auth component more personalized.You can copy

`/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php`

to

`/app/controllers/components/auth.php`

and edit the `__setDefaults` function in the new copy.You can specify your own auth error message by change the value of key `authError` in `$defaults`.Set it an empty string if you want to show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in Cake 2.x and it worked. Put this in your Controller's `beforeFilter()` function:

```
$this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario.

When a user is logged in, '/' routes to a dashboard action in a controller. When a user is not logged in, however, I wanted the user to be able to request either mydomain.com or mydomain.com/users/login **without** getting an authError message.

If the user requested any other page, however, I wanted the “not authorized” authError message to display as it normally would.

Here's my solution: in the beforeFilter in the AppController

```
if($this->request->here == '/' && !$this->Auth->loggedIn()){
    $this->Auth->allow('dashboard'); //temporarily allow the dashboard action
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));   //manually redirect to login screen
}
```

Because of the way routes work, if the user requests '/' they will *not* receive an auth error. However, if they request /controller_name/dashboard, they *will* receive an auth error because $this->Auth->allow('dashboard') only fires if they request '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I practice another better way than *[Young's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952907/1787600)*. In *AppController* please set following code :

```
function beforeFilter(){
    ... ... ...
    //set auth message custom id, if required.
    $this->Auth->flash['key'] = 'YOUR-ID-HERE';
    //set auth message custom attributes e.g. class etc., if required
    $this->Auth->flash['params']=array('class'=>'YOUR-CLASS-HERE');
    //set auth message custom element path, if required
    $this->Auth->flash['element'] = 'YOUR-ELEMENT-PATH-HERE';
    ... ... ...
}
```

I hope it will be better than customization Core Libraries for a simple work.

Answer (score 0):

I was with a similar issue, but I'm using CakePHP 3.4. I solved editing `config/routes.php`:

```
//$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
$routes->redirect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```