# CakePHP custom flash for loginError

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an error like:

```
<?php
    $this->Auth->loginError = "No, you fool!  That's not the right password!";
?>
```

But I have a custom flash element. How do I use that? and how I pass in extra information like in the below example.

Sample flash:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Your settings have been updated', 'flash', array('myclass' => 'success'));
```

Custom flash element:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message<?php if(isset($myclass)) { echo ' ' . $myclass; } ?>">
 <div class="content">
   <?php if(isset($header)) { echo '<h3>' . $header . '</h3>'; } ?>
   <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Auth messages are stored in `this->Session->flash('auth');`. So you could just add another element that only prints messages intended for `auth` and style it however you want.

Answer (score 2):

This may be old, but I had a similar problem, and solved it by assigning the layout to the AuthComponent member field **flashElement**;

```
$this->Auth->flashElement = 'custom_flash';
```

See [customn auth flash.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950417/avoid-cakephps-auth-component-to-display-authentication-error-messages)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$this->Auth->flash['element'] = 'flash/auth';
```

will use te element in

app/View/Elements/flash/auth.ctp

["Authentication — CakePHP Cookbook v2.x documentation"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages)

Answer (score 1):

It is 3 years late but here is a complete answer. In you AppController in beforeFilter method use following:

```
$this->Auth->flash = array(
    'element' => 'flash',
    'key' => 'auth',
    'params' => array(
        'myclass' => 'your auth message class',
        'header' => 'your auth message header',
    )
);
```

As suggested in in [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#displaying-auth-related-flash-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, but this might help some. You can set the element in the AppController like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = [
        'Auth' => [
            'flash' => ['element' => 'auth'],
        ],
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Session->setFlash method writes a message into the $session variable available on the cakephp views. in your element you'd have to do something like this:

```
<?php echo $session->read('Message.flash.message')?>
```

Have a look at the [setFlash api](http://api.cakephp.org/class/session-component#method-SessionComponentsetFlash). You can add extra parameters there.

If you need to see the output, try:

```
<?php debug($session->read('Message.flash')?>
```

That will show you the flash array with the message and other associated data which you can then use in your custom handler.

Comment: But how I pass in the extra information like I do with my setFlash on the loginError?